# How can I migrate MariaDB to Aurora

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, mariadb, devops, amazon-aurora

I have running MariaDB Database and I want to migrate it to Amazon Aurora, how can I migrate It to Amazon Aurora

Comment: Looking at there is no direct migration to AWS Aurora, maybe try MariaDB > PostgreSQL > AWS AurorA. I'm not experienced in DB migration but I think this is worth the shot. https://www.amazonaws.cn/en/dms/

Comment: Since MariaDB should be compatible with MySQL. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_MySQL2Aurora.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This migration is doable in multiple ways. Few questions to begin with :

1. Which version of Maria DB are you currently on and which version of Aurora Mysql are you planning to move to?
2. Are you already on RDS MariaDB? If yes, the migration might be a bit simple with snapshot restore.

If you are not currently on RDS MariaDB:

1. MariaDB 10.0 to Aurora 5.6 and MariaDB 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 to Aurora 5.7 should be doable without much complications. This is based on the compatibility shown here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-vs-mysql-compatibility/ . You would most likely export your data using mysqldump and then import them via SQL apis or LOAD from S3 that Aurora supports.
2. For any other migrations, you might need to do additional steps since you'd be crossing the compatibility boundaries.

Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/CHAP_MySQL2Aurora.html

If you are already on RDS Maria DB:

1. Try snapshot restore. A direct snapshot restore might not get you where you need to get, but thats the starting point for you.

Doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Migrating.RDSMySQL.Import.html